# What is bits in computer science

Tags: 64-bit, bit

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptzGI9VaZmQ) on youtube about the bits. After watching it I have a confusion what the actual size does a number, string or any character takes. What I have understood from the video is.

1= 00000001   // 1 bit

3= 00000011  // 2 bits

511 = 111111111 // 9bits

4294967295= 11111111111111111111111111111111   //32 bit

1.5 = ? // ?

I just want to know above given statement expect in decimal point are correct ? or all numeric , string or any character take 8 byte. I am using 64 bit operating system.

And what is the binary code of decimal value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how many bits/bytes are used to represent a given number or character. I'll try to cover the common cases:

### Integer (whole number) values

Since [most](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bits-per-byte) systems use 8-bits per byte, [integer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whole_number) numbers are usually represented as a multiple of 8 bits:

- 8 bits (1 byte) is typical for the [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) `char` datatype.
- 16 bits (2 bytes) is typical for `int` or `short` values.
- 32 bits (4 bytes) is typical for `int` or `long` values.

Each successive bit is used to represent a value twice the size of the previous one, so the first bit represents one, the second bit represents two, the third represents four, and so on. If a bit is set to `1`, the value it represents is added to the "total" value of the number as a whole, so the 4-bit value `1101` (8, 4, 2, 1) is 8+4+1 = 13.

Note that the **zeroes are still counted as bits**, even for numbers such as 3, because they're still *necessary* to represent the number. For example:

- `00000011` represents a decimal value of 3 as an 8-bit binary number.
- `00000111` represents a decimal value of 7 as an 8-bit binary number.

The zero in the first number is used to distinguish it from the second, even if it's not "set" as `1`.

An "unsigned" 8-bit variable can represent `2^8` (256) values, in the range 0 to 255 inclusive. "Signed" values (i.e. numbers which can be negative) are often described as using a single bit to indicate whether the value is positive (`0`) or negative (`1`), which would give an effective range of `2^7` (-127 to +127) either way, but since there's not much point in having two different ways to represent zero (-0 and +0), [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is commonly used to allow a slightly greater storage range: -12**8** to +127.

### Decimal (fractional) values

Numbers such as 1.5 are usually represented as [IEEE floating point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). A 32-bit IEEE floating point value uses 32 bits like a typical `int` value, but **will use those bits differently**. I'd suggest reading the Wikipedia article if you're interested in the technical details of how it works - I hope that you like mathematics.

Alternatively, non-integer numbers may be represented using a [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) format; this was a fairly common occurrence in the early days of DOS gaming, before [FPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) became a standard feature of desktop machines, and fixed point arithmetic is still used today in some situations, such as [embedded systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system).

### Text

Simple ASCII or [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) text is usually represented as a series of 8-bit bytes - in other words it's a series of integers, with each numeric value representing a single character code. For example, an 8-bit value of `00100000` (32) represents the ASCII space () character.

Alternative 8-bit encodings (such as [JIS X 0201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201)) map those 2^8 number values to different visible characters, whilst yet other encodings may use 16-bit or 32-bit values for each character instead.

Unicode character sets (such a the 8-bit [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or 16-bit [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) are more complicated; a single UTF-16 character might be represented as a *single* 16-bit value or a *pair* of 16-bit values, whilst UTF-8 characters can be anywhere from *one* 8-bit byte to *four* 8-bit bytes!

### Endian-ness

You should also be aware that values spanning more than a single 8-bit byte are typically [byte-ordered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in one of two ways: *little* endian, or *big* endian.

- **Little Endian:** A 16-bit value of 512 would be represented as `11111111` `00000001` (i.e. smallest-value bits come first).
- **Big Endian:** A 16-bit value of 512 would be represented as `00000001` `11111111` (i.e. largest-value bits come first).

You may also hear of mixed-endian, middle-endian, or bi-endian representations - see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for further information.

Comment: So if I have to represent 511. So it will use 3 byte 00000101 00000001 00000001 . Am I correct?

Comment: No; assuming that a number is stored as an "unsigned" integer, the maximum value possible is `(2^x)-1`, where `x` is the number of bits. So, for an 8-bit value, the maximum number is `(2^8)-1`, which is 255. For 9 bits, you can store values up to 511, and for 10 bits you can store values up to 1023. Therefore, the minimum number of bits needed to represent 511 would be 9 - but, since values are typically 8, 16, or 32 bits in size, you'd need to store it as a 16-bit value. The extra "unused" bits would all be set to zero: `00000001 11111111`

Comment: @amit You could do it that way, if you really wanted to. At lot of this is about space efficiency, time efficiency, accuracy, precision and range. Your representation takes a lot of space, with each byte storing only 10 values (0-9 decimal). There are similar formats, called binary coded decimal (BCD), that put 2 decimal digits in each byte. But, first understand the 1s place, the 2s place, the 4s place,… and the range of values a binary number of n digits can represent.

Comment: @GoBusto (2^x)-1. why -1 from the value. 2^8 = 256

Comment: Because one of the 256 possibilities is zero: `00000000`

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between a bit, a byte.

1 bit is a single digit 0 or 1 in base 2.

1 byte = 8 bits.

Yes the statements you gave are correct.

Binary code of 1.5 will be 001.100. However this is how we interpret binary. The way computer stores numbers is different and is based on compiler, platform. For example C uses IEEE 754 format. Google about it to learn more.

Your OS is 64 bit means your CPU architecture is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

a bit is one binary digit e.g 0 or 1.
a byte is eight bits, or two hex digits
A Nibble is half a byte or 1 hex digit

Words get a bit more complex. Originally it was the number of bytes required to cover the range of addresses available in memory. As we had a lot of hybrids and memory schemes. Word is usually two-bytes, a double word, 4 bytes etc.

In a computing everything comes down to binary, a combination of 0s and 1s. Characters, decimal numbers etc are representations. 
So the character 0 is 7 (or 8 bit ascii) is 00110000 in binary, 30 in hex, and 48 as decimal (base 10) number. It's only '0' if you choose to 'see' it as a single byte character.

Representing numbers with decimal points is even more varied. There are many accepted ways of doing that, but they are conventions not rules.

Have a look for 1 and 2s complement, gray code, BCD, floating point representation and such to get more of an idea.